# When I write " #!!!" in Spyder, it shows a tick on the left. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I am using Anaconda-Spyder in learning Python. I accidentally saw a blue tick on the left when I write `#!!!` in my source code. Why? What does this mean?

[image: Blue ticks at the left]

Answer (score 9):

This is a mark for you to allow to highlight places in the code with todo-like comments.

a) In *Tools->Preferences* dialog go to *Editor -> Advanced settings* tab and untick *Display code annotations*. Or don't untick, but find the list of comment tags that cause the blue mark to appear.

b) Don't forget to add a space after # to be pep8-compliant.